# JavaFX Scene Builder custom tab

Tags: java, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I have created own custom control for JavaFX. It is working well when I have add it manually into FXML file. And it is "invisible" for Java Scene Builder when I tried to import it. So, I have next code (extremely simplified version):
**MyTab.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.* ?>
<?import tafm.javafx.controls.MyTab?>


<fx:root type="javafx.scene.control.Tab" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
</fx:root>
```

**MyTab.java**

```
package tafm.javafx.controls;

import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MyTab extends Tab {

    public MyTab() {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("MyTab.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);
        fxmlLoader.setClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();            
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }
}
```

I have build an jar file with this control and tried to import it into JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0. It is imported just with one error "Not a node: tafm.javafx.controls.MyTab.class" and there is no MyTab control available.

Then I change this class (together with fxml) as:

```
public class MyTab extends HBox
```

(just for testing purposes). It is successfully loaded into SB!
So, as I understand, it is impossible to create an own "Tab". Is it true? 
Sure, I can manually edit the fxml files, but I would like to do it in SB. Does some workaround exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Tab`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Tab.html) in JavaFX is not inherited from the [`Node`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html). It is also clear from the message you get.

All custom controls have to be part of the scene graph i.e. based on the [`Node`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html). It is preferable that all custom controls inherit from [`Control`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Control.html), which will simplify and standardize their development.

Comment: It is clear. But does some workaround exists? How SB working itself? It contains Tab in the control list. Ok, understood. It is impossible until Oracle team decides to improve SB.